# Needs a different set of data when override as json rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have override as_json in model, looks like this:

```
class Widget < ApplicationController
    def as_json(options = {})
        super(only: [:id, :number, :code, :item, :idbilling, 
                     :total, :status, :explanation
                    ])
    end
end
```

And I want to use as json for Widget to show different set of data. So I use this in a controller:

```
def some_action
    widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
    render json: widget.as_json(only: [:id, :idbilling]), status: :ok
end
```

But I get the same result as the override method: the result show not only id and idbilling, but also number, code, and so on.

How can I show the set of data that I want to show?

I have read tutorials, search in stackoverflow, but they only wrote to just pass in my options like I normally would into the as_json method like I wrote in some_action method. But it did not work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you'd be better off leaving `as_json` alone and switching to jbuilder or something like that for building your JSON (or equivalently, don't override `as_json` and write `as_json` calls tailored for your controller's needs in the controllers). The root of your problem is that you're mixing controller/view concerns into your models.

Comment: Please note `def as_json(options = {})` where `options` is an argument. However in your method body you do not reference this at all. Thus it has no impact when you pass a new `Hash` though. However `default = {only: [:id, :number, :code, :item, :idbilling, 
                     :total, :status, :explanation
                    ]}; super(default.merge(options))` would work accordingly

Answer (score 0):

That's what `super` does. If you want to overwride `super`, you could pass an extra param to your `as_json` method which will tell super to just use what you passed and not include any additional information.

```
def as_json(options = {}, default: true)
  json = {}

  if default
    json[:only] = [:id, :number, :code, :item, :idbilling, :total, :status, :explanation]
  end

  super json
end

def some_action
  widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
  render json: widget.as_json(only: [:id, :idbilling], default: false), status: :ok
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Widget < ApplicationController
    def as_json(options = { only: [:id, :number, :code, :item, :idbilling, 
                                   :total, :status, :explanation] })
        super
    end
end
```